# Como preencher uma tag <li> criada com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Quero preencher as tags `li` com o que tem na array `nomes`.

Eu sei para que o atributo `value` serve, é longe do que eu quero fazer. Mas deixei aí pra ilustrar.

```
    var nomes = ["Diego", "Gabriel", "Lucas"];
    var listaUl = document.querySelector('div#app ol.lista'); 

    function listarNomes(nomes) {
        for(let i = 0; i <= nomes.length-1; i++){
            var item = document.createElement('li');
            item.setAttribute('name', nomes[i]); //é aqui que preciso de ajuda
            listaUl.appendChild(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Em vez de `i <= nomes.length-1`, use `i < nomes.length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito a pergunta, mas, para fazer o que descreveu o **setAttribute()** não ajudaria, pois, ele serve para setar valores para atributos Html como o próprio nome do método demonstra, no seu caso um [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) supriria o que deseja:

```js
var nomes = ["Diego", "Gabriel", "Lucas"];
var listaUl = document.querySelector('div#app ol.lista');

function listarNomes(nomes) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= nomes.length - 1; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.textContent = nomes[i];
    listaUl.appendChild(item);
  }
}

listarNomes(nomes)
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <ol class="lista"></ol>
</div>
```